# PGF of a sequence of random variables defined via difference equation

Tags: probability

Suppose $p \in (0,1)$. In a sequence of trials, let $u_n$ denote the probability of success of the $n$th trial. We have $u_0 = 1$, $u_1 = 0$ and for $n \geq 3$:

$$
u_n = (u_{n-2} + 1 - p)p^2
$$

I would like to work out the probability generating function of the $u_n$'s, i.e. the function

$$
U(s) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty u_n s^n
$$

But I very quickly get stuck with my working. I have something like

$$u_n = p^n + p^2(1-p)(1 + p^2 + p^4 + \dots + p^{n-2})$$

if $n$ is even, and

$$u_n = p^2(1-p)(1 + p^2 + p^4 + \dots + p^{n-3})$$

if $n$ is odd, but I don't know where to go from here. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} r^k=\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$ to get your $u_n$. Check your expression of $u_n$. I think something wrong in your $u_n$. Note
\begin{eqnarray}
U(s)&=&u_0+u_1s+\sum_{n=2}^\infty u_ns^n\\
&=&1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty(u_{n-2}+1-p)p^2s^n\\
&=&1+s^2\sum_{n=2}^\infty u_{n-2}s^{n-2}+(1-p)p^2 s^2\sum_{n=2}^\infty s^{n-2}\\
&=&1+s^2U(s)+\frac{(1-p)p^2 s^2}{1-s}
\end{eqnarray}
and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
U(s)&=&\frac{1-s+(1-p)p^2 s^2}{(1-s^2)(1-s)}\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}(p^2-p^3)\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}+\frac14(2-3p^2+3p^3)\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac14(2+p^2-p^3)\frac{1}{1+x}\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}(p^2-p^3)\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^n+\frac14(2-3p^2+3p^3)\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n+\frac14(2+p^2-p^3)\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^n.
\end{eqnarray}
So
$$ u_n=\frac{1}{2}(p^2-p^3)(n+1)+\frac14(2-3p^2+3p^3)+(-1)^n\frac14(2+p^2-p^3). $$

Comment: OK, so I can substitute in $1-p^n$ for the first series ($n$ even) and $1-p^{n-1}$ for the second ($n$ odd), plus an extra divisor of $1-p^2$. Assuming this is correct, they're still very ugly and I don't know how to deal with the two separate cases

Comment: @TomOffer, please see the answer for these cases.

Comment: Thank you! I have calculated an expression for U(s) now... unfortunately none of the terms cancel but oh well!

Comment: You have missed a $p^2$ term in the third line of your calculations. Thanks for showing me this method though, it works nicely!